# Center two pictures of different sizes in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, beamer-metropolis

I have the following code for a beamer presentation:

```
\begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=.22]{img/towards}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=.25]{img/mac}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
```

The result is not distributed proportionally. For instance, there is very little margin on the right and much more on the left. As a result, the whole appears towards the right. Is there a way to display this more centered?

Here are the two images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We haven't your images, so we can only use `example-image˙ from graphicx package. Determining their sizes with column width instead of scaled images gives an (expected) nice result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck} % <---
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}  % <---
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated comment: `graphicx` is not the source of the various `example-image`s. The original ones (`-a`, `-b`, `-c`, `-1x1` etc.) are from the `mwe` package, the one you used is from the `duckuments` package.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., thank you for information. Thus means that `includegraphicx` call `mwe` and `duckuments` packages?

Comment: No. The packages doesn't have to be called to make the images available. The image files are in the default search paths.